# wpf combo change event triggered when form loads

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am having a problem, when window loads, the 'selection_change' event associated with 'combo box' control is getting triggered when the window loads first time. Why its occuring and How to restrict it please?

Regards

Comment: Are you sure you are not programatically setting the selected element of the combo-box in the constructor, or some other place in your code? If you do, then the event will be invoked.

Comment: can you show us the code where you are dealing with Combobox, may be u are doing something that is triggering the event...

Comment: @shekhar, nothing special, just this in the xaml file: <ComboBox Height="23" Margin="130,20,168,0" Name="cmbUsers" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="cmbUsers_SelectionChanged" /> and the corresponding function in code behind is gettting invoked.

Comment: as suggested by @Meleak set a break point on selection changed and see the Call Stack.. if you don't understand it than post it here.. we may have a look and Fix what's messing it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that code, the `SelectionChanged` event won't get raised. Create a new project, paste it and try it for yourself.

My guess is pretty much the same as *Sekhar*_ *Pro*'s, you're populating your `ComboBox` from code behind, and something in there causes the SelectedItem to change.
Investigate the `cmbUsers.SelectedItem` in the `cmbUsers_SelectionChanged` event handler to see if it has some value or is null in the debugger. Also, look in the Call Stack to find what caused this event to be raised.

**Example code**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cmbUsers.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Test" });
        cmbUsers.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    private void cmbUsers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbUsers.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cmbUsers.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**The Call Stack looks like this for me in the event handler**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a normal Behavior, some where you must be doing something like setting SelectedItem, etc which in turn is triggering the event. Check thorough your form's life-cycle events and see if you are doing something like this, may be in Load or Activate event or somewhere in the Constructors.

Comment: hi, I remember, i had similar problems on win forms applications also and i did resolved it there by using 'selection_change_commited' event instead of 'selection_changed' event. In WPF, the 'commited' version doesn't exist :(